# Scala-Maven project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide, maven-scala-plugin

I am trying to use  [this Scala project](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark).

The project contains **maven dependencies** so I have created a **pom.xml** and then I have imported the project as a maven project in *eclipse*.

In order to test the project I tried to add a **Scala class**, but I'm surprised that I can't.

this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.group-name</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.6</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opencypher</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-cypher</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.5</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

i imported it to eclipse as a maven project then i build the maven project.

**My questions are**:

1)  is my approach right ?

2) if 1) is right then how can I use this Scala project with maven ??

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't" ?? What is your `pom.xml` ? How did you imported it to eclipse? Is eclipse complaining about anything while importing the project? We know nothing about your approach till now

Comment: I' cant add a Scala class in a maven project, eclipse don't let me do that. for the importaion of pom:
File>Import>Maven>EXISTING MAVEN PROJECT and the import succeeded

Comment: Do you have scala plugin installed in eclipse?

Comment: yes it is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import a **Scala Maven Project** on *eclipse*, you need to :

•   install Scala plugin for eclipse (HELP>ECLIPS MARKETPLACE>”search for Scala ide”)

•   Install Maven Integration for Scala IDE(HELP>INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE>”search for http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/”)

•   Import project as Existing Maven Projects

Answer (score -1):

Try the below POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.group-name</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opencypher</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-cypher</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: this is the same pom as mine ?!

Comment: Yes replace the above pom with this one and save it and build it. So that the new jars will be downloaded in the repository

Comment: the jars are already downloaded, i didn't understand your point ?

Comment: Sometimes eclipse build a cache when downloading jars from repository. So try replacing the file and save it. Also better if you remove the old downloaded jars